# How to store a MySQL query (JSON) in android sqlite database?

Tags: android, mysql, json, sqlite, parsing

I am trying to writing code so that my android application can query a MySQL database and then retrieve the data in JSON which it then parses. I would then like to take the data and insert it into the application's local database on SQLite. I would like this data to be updated at a set frequency as well.

This is the JSON array and HTTP Get protocol activity.

```
package com.connector;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class whitehat extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

TextView txt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
// Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources  
// but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.  
LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());  
txt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());  
rootLayout.addView(txt);  
setContentView(rootLayout);  

// Set the text and call the connect function.  
txt.setText("Connecting..."); 
//call the method to run the data retreival
txt.setText(getServerData(KEY_121)); 



}
public static final String KEY_121 = "http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/hellomysql/mysqlcon.php"; //i use my real ip here



private String getServerData(String returnString) {

InputStream is = null;

String result = "";
//the year data to send
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("publisher","Penguin Books UK"));

//http post
try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}

//convert response to string
try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}
//parse json data
try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+
                        ", isbn: "+json_data.getString("isbn")+
                        ", title: "+json_data.getString("title")+
                        ", publisher: "+json_data.getString("publisher")
                );
                //Get an output to the screen
                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
        }
}catch(JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
return returnString; 
}    

}
```

The following two are the database related activities.

```
package com.example.database;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_ISBN = "isbn";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_PUBLISHER = "publisher";    
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "books";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "titles";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table titles (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "isbn text not null, title text not null, " 
    + "publisher text not null);";

private final Context context; 

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);        }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}    

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a title into the database---
public long insertTitle(String isbn, String title, String publisher) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_ISBN, isbn);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PUBLISHER, publisher);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
//---deletes a particular title---
public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) 
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
     "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
//---retrieves all the titles---
public Cursor getAllTitles() 
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
            KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_ISBN,
            KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_PUBLISHER}, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
}
//---retrieves a particular title---
public Cursor getTitle(long rowId) throws SQLException 
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
             KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_ISBN, 
            KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_PUBLISHER
            }, 
        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
        null,
        null, 
        null, 
        null, 
        null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
//---updates a title---
public boolean updateTitle(long rowId, String isbn, 
String title, String publisher) 
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_ISBN, isbn);
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_PUBLISHER, publisher);
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                     KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
}
```

The second one is:

```
public class DatabaseActivity extends Activity {
DBAdapter db;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    db = new DBAdapter(this); 
    System.out.println("bool1");
    insert();
disAll();
    //update();
    //dis(3);
    //del(5);
}
private void update(){ 

    db.open();
if (db.updateTitle(1, 
     "0470285818", 
"C# 2008 Programmer's Reference",
"Wrox Press"))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Update successful.", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Update failed.", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //-------------------
    //---retrieve the same title to verify---
    Cursor c = db.getTitle(1);
    if (c.moveToFirst())        
        DisplayTitle(c);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No title found", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
    //-------------------        
db.close();

}
private void insert(){ 

    db.open();        
    long id;
    id = db.insertTitle(
     "0470285819",
    "Teach yourself Java",
    "Wrox");        
    id = db.insertTitle(
    "047017661y",
    "Professional Windows 07 Gadgets Programming",
    "Wrox");
    System.out.println("bool211");
    db.close();
}
private void disAll(){

    db.open();
/*Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {          
         System.out.println("bool2");
            DisplayTitle(c);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    else
     System.out.println("boo3l");*/
    try{
Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {          
System.out.println("bool2");
                DisplayTitle(c);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
     System.out.println(e);
    }
    db.close();
}

private void   dis(   int   j){

    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getTitle(j);
    if (c.moveToFirst())        
        DisplayTitle(c);
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "No title found", 
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();
}        

 private void   del(   int   j){

    db.open();
    if (db.deleteTitle(j))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete successful.", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete failed.", 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
    db.close();        
}
public void DisplayTitle(Cursor c)
{
 System.out.println("bool");
    Toast.makeText(this, 
            "id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
            "ISBN: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
            "TITLE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
            "PUBLISHER:  " + c.getString(3),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
} 
}
```

If anyone is able to help it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your getServerData method will return a JSONString. In your getServerData method u have a Log Statement, which is actually parsing the JSONObject. Instead of logging it u can call the insertTitle in the dbAdapter class.

To make this work u have to do some changes. Ur DBAdapter constructor should look like this

```
  public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        this.db=DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

Ur create statement should look like this. U r getting the id from the server. So there is no point having the id as auto increment.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table titles (_id integer primary key , "
    + "isbn text not null, title text not null, " 
    + "publisher text not null);";
```

Ur insertTitle should be like this. Similarly change ur update and other methods.

```
public long insertTitle(String _id,String isbn, String title, String publisher) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_ID, _id);
    initialValues.put(KEY_ISBN, isbn);
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PUBLISHER, publisher);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

But make sure u create the dbAdapter object outside the for loop. Hope this will help

Comment: How would you go about calling the insertTitle into the getServerData?

Comment: In whitehat class do the folowing, public DBAdapter dbAdapter =new DBAdapter(this). Replace the log.i statement in getServerData with dbAdapter.insertTitle(json_data.getInt("id"),json_data.getString("isbn"),json_data.getString("title"),json_data.getString("publisher"));

Comment: I have done what you have suggested but when debugging the application  it throws an error message and suspends the main activity.

Do you know anyway in which to solve this?

Comment: it doesn't matter it turns out I had misspelt something.

Do you have anyway in which I can check if the data is stored within the application database?

Comment: in command prompt do the following,
1.adb -s emulator-5554 shell
give ur emulator id.
2. cd /data/data/<ur package name>/databases
3. ls 
check whether there is books.db
4. if so sqlite3 books.db
5. .tables will give u all the tables
6. select command to check ur data

Comment: I am getting an issue where it is telling me that it Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method insertTitle(int, String, String, String, String, String, String, String) from the type DBAdapter.
What is going wrong all of a sudden?

Comment: I can sense 2 things. one is have u created a DBAdapter instance and called it. insertTitle is a nonstatic method so it has to be called by an instance of DBAdapter. two there are lot of parameters in the insertTitle have u changed the code?

Comment: I accidentally misspelt part of the code which caused it to stop working. It is working fine now.
Thanks for your help.